# How to fix Uninitialized string offset: error on a checkbox in WP Settings API

Tags: plugin-development, settings-api, variables, wp-debug

I am trying to create an options page with a checkbox field. The checkbox is working fine but when I uncheck it and save settings, an error string shows on

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\wp-content\plugins\test\admin\options.php on line 55
```

Here is the main settings code:

```
register_setting('twb_settings', 'twb_option', '' );

add_settings_section('twb_section', 'General Settings', '', __FILE__);

add_settings_field(  'hide_avatar',  'Hide Avatar',  'hide_vatar_fn',  __FILE__,  'twb_section');

function hide_vatar_fn()
{
    $options = get_option( 'twb_option' );      
    echo'<input type="checkbox" id="hide_avatar" name="twb_option[hide_avatar]" value="1" ' . checked(1, $options['hide_avatar'], false) . '/>';
}
```

If I add a sanitization call back in `register_settings`, then the error get replace with `Undefined Variable` error.

If I deactivate `WP_Debug` mode, all errors are gone.

Comment: and what is there on line 55?

Comment: echo'<input type="checkbox" id="hide_avatar" name="twb_option[hide_avatar]" value="1" ' . checked(1, $options['hide_avatar'], false) . '/>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `$options` is a string and not an array.

It is always better to validate that the $options are in the format you are expecting especially in development time when you are likely to switch formats and too lazy to clean the DB when doing that.

something like

```
if (!isset($options['hide_avatar'])) 
  $options['hide_avatar'] = 0;
```

Might have still resulted in a strange error, but it would have been little more easier to understand exactly where and maybe why.

Comment: where I am supposed to add this code? before echo'<input type="checkbox" ....  ?

Comment: you are not "supposed" to add that code anywhere, it is just a possible example to what you should do. The exact code and how/where to use it depends on how you prefer to write your code.

Comment: My code was ended up like following and it fixed the issue.

`$options = get_option( 'twb_option' ); 

if (!isset($options['hide_avatar'])) 
$options['hide_avatar'] = 0;

echo'<input type="checkbox" id="hide_avatar" name="twb_option[hide_avatar]" value="1" ' . checked(1, $options['hide_avatar'], false) . '/>';`

and the problem was resolved.